# How to setup general errors in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

The [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) has Validation and [`error`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Validator/Validation#error) method to setup errors while validating `POST`ed form data.

Should I use `$c->Validation->error` to setup general errors. Such as *login password error* or *captured database exception*

Example #1:

```
$c->validation->error( auth =>  [ 'required_level', 'Forbidden', $rl ] );
$c->render( 'auth/login',  status => 403 );
```

Example #2:

```
eval{ $package->db->update( $data ); 1}   or do {
    $v->error( update => [ db => $@,  $package ] );
    return $self->render( 'package/edit' );
}
```

I am doubt because actually I have no `auth` and `update` fields.

Please advice. Should I continue to use `Validation` object to setup such general errors or there are other best practices exist?

Comment: I would render error messages manually when they are not related to form validation. What you are proposing mixed up things and breaks the separation of concerns.

Comment: @simbabque: How about `->error` helper which will allow to setup error: `$c->error( error_name => [ 'error_str', @context_data ]` and the `->errors` which will return controller and validation errors: { `%{ $c->{ error }, %{ $v->{ error } } }`